# Make an alert box with a user defined character

Tags: javascript

I am making a piece of code to make a prompt appear with a user defined character. What I mean is, the user typed a dec or hex character value, and it will make a prompt appear with the character. This is my code:

```
var userChar = prompt("Type an ASCII hex or dec value");
alert("&#" + userChar + ";");
```

Let's say the user typed "220" for the character "Ü", instead of the alert displaying "Ü", it displays "`&#220;`" How do I make it display "Ü" instead of `&#220;`?

Comment: fromCharCode: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `alert(String.fromCharCode(userChar))` to convert Ascii to string.